# How to get bokeh widget to interact with plot .on_change()

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a graph with 3 lines, one for each column in my dataframe. I want to be able to select in the widget which lines are shown in the visualization. The plot comes up with the widget but selecting columns in the widget does not effect the visualization. I think my mistake is in my update function but I don't know how to get the plot to update.

[picture of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGOSh.png)

[dataframe head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuWQt.png)

```
# Load in flights and inspect
data = pd.read_csv('project_data.csv', index_col='DATE', parse_dates=True)

# These are the column names
available_people = ['merissa_steps', 'sherida_steps', 'tova_steps']

def modify_doc(doc):

    def make_dataset(person_list):

        by_person = data[person_list]

        return ColumnDataSource(by_person)

    def make_plot(src, people):
        # Blank plot with correct labels
        p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="Everyone's Steps", plot_height=200, plot_width=500)
        for person in people:
            p.line(source = src, x = 'DATE', y = person, color='gray')

        return p

    # Update function takes three default parameters
    def update(attr, old, new):
        # Get the list of carriers for the graph
        people_to_plot = [person_selection.labels[i] for i in 
                            person_selection.active]

        # Make a new dataset based on the selected carriers and the 
        # make_dataset function defined earlier
        new_src = make_dataset(people_to_plot)

        # Update the source used the quad glpyhs
        src.data.update(new_src.data)

    person_selection = CheckboxGroup(labels=available_people, active = [0, 1])
    person_selection.on_change('active', update)

    controls = WidgetBox(person_selection)

    initial_people = [person_selection.labels[i] for i in person_selection.active]

    src = make_dataset(initial_people)

    p = make_plot(src, initial_people)

    layout = row(controls, p)
    doc.add_root(layout)

# Set up an application
handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)
```

Comment: The error in my code is that ```src.data.update(new_src.data)``` is not actually updating my data source. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question!
`src.data.update(new_src.data)`
only updates rows it doesn't change columns. So did pd.melt(...) all the way in the beginning so that the update I wanted to do was a row wise update instead of a column wise update and now my program ran the way I wanted to.